# How to install ACR38 card reader

Tags: 14.04, card-reader

Tried to install this driver: wiki.homebank.kz/attach/CardReaderSetup/ACR38_Driver_Lnx_1000_P.zip

but didn't have success. I followed the same steps as in readme file, but faced problems when i was trying to do ./configure so i've installed:

```
libpcsclite-dev
libusb-dev
```

Then when i did make i faced tons of errors. What the correct way of installing ACR38 Cardreader drivers in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste use the apt-get to install the driver: `sudo apt-get install pcscd libccid`

Answer (score 2):

I had to do

sudo apt-get install libacsccid1

acsscid is a project that provides a driver for the ACR38

After restarting pcscd, it picked up the driver and I could use the reader.